# How to update Java JRE in Lion?

Tags: macos, security, java

Sofware update says everything is up to date, however Java Preferences says it's running Version 6 Update 29.

The Java website says there is a newer version: Version 6 Update 31 with critical security fixes.

Is there any way I can update this or do I have to sit around and wait for Apple to release this through software update?  It is a critical security fix isn't it?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Oracle Java downloads](http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp):

> Apple supplies their own version of Java. Use the Software Update
>   feature (available on the Apple menu) to check that you have the most
>   up-to-date version of Java for your Mac.

I seriously recommend not to use any other way, but OS X Software Update.

Comment: That kind of sucks, Apple doesn't seem the least bit concerned about releasing Java updates :(

Comment: I'm picking this answer as there's really no other reliable way to go about this.  That said, they did just update today, horray! :)

Comment: [Java 1.7u4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) is now available directly from Oracle.